# TypeError: 'undefined ' is not a function ( evaluating 'window.attachEvent ("onunload", a)')

Tags: angularjs, npm, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test the angularjs application using jasmine by karma test and I get the following error.

TypeError: 'undefined ' is not a function ( evaluating 'window.attachEvent ("onunload", a)')

at C:/../app/css/PIE/PIE.JS
nad I am not sure why PIE is used for
(I am learning to use karma testing.)

Comment: Why don't you use `$window`? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Isn't attachEvent deprecated?

Comment: trying to test in browser phantomJS.

Comment: I would guess that PIE.JS is [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/). But, why have you included it if you don't know what it does?

Comment: I am just trying to test the already existing angular js application.I am goign to try removing it and see if it makes any change